# Change background photo on selection

Tags: javascript

I have a background photo - when clicked you can choose a new photo and change the current photo, it works great :

```
  <div class="uploader">
                           <div class="imagePreview" id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url(http://i.pravatar.cc/500?img=7);"> </div>
                           <input type="file" id="imageUpload">
    </div>
```

//JS

```
function readURL(input) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = function(e) {
           $('#imagePreview').css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
           $('#imagePreview').hide();
           $('#imagePreview').fadeIn(850);
       }
       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
}
$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
   readURL(this);
});
```

It may be basic to ask, but now when I would like to **duplicate** this `div` to have 4 different photos with the same effect (click to chose a new photo from each div) I will need to *duplicate this JS code*.

How do I write this `JS` to listen to a change in `every` one of the *duplicated divs* then pass an argument of the current `imagePrivew` that changed, and set **its** background as the selected file?

Answer (score 0):

I tagged them differently and then **JS** :

```
function readURL(input,id) {
   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = function(e) {

         var div = document.getElementById( id );
           $(div).css('background-image', 'url('+e.target.result +')');
           $(div).hide();
           $(div).fadeIn(850);



       }
       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
   }
}
$("#imageUpload1,#imageUpload2,#imageUpload3,#imageUpload4").change(function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
   readURL(this,id);
});
```